# Android rotate really large bitmaps fast

Tags: android, bitmap, rotation, android-bitmap

I am trying to rotate really large bitmaps inside android like 3000x5000 px with

> matrix.postRotate()

but the problem is that this procedure despite the fact that it is very common inside android and it is working properly...it is slow for such large bitmaps...almost 5 seconds on my phone. Due to project limitations, resizing it is not an option here. Does anyone has another suggestion for faster rotation?

I am using CameraX and onImageSavedCallback.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "despite the fact that it is very common inside android" -- perhaps less than you are expecting (compared to rendering rotated views on the GPU). Are you trying to create a new `Bitmap` that is rotated? If so, does Logcat suggest that you are going through lots of GC? Beyond that, use Android Studio's profiler or logging to determine exactly where you are spending your time.

Comment: Hi, CameraX creates the file and saves the bitmap in internal files dir. Then when I need it, I load it, rotate it, do some cropping and show the result to the user. I have put logs...and the most time is during rotation, almost 5 seconds.

Comment: If you are gonna crop anyway then why not do rotation after cropping?

Comment: There are also ml models involved..so I have to rotate before cropping.

Comment: Try to load the image into opencv Mat instead of bitmap, and rotate the Mat object.